# Physical theories and Mathematics

Tags: physics, mathematical-physics, math-history, quantum-field-theory, special-relativity

I study pure mathematics. In pure mathematics, we begin from some axioms and obtain theorems. I am also interested in studying physics.
I have two questions about the relationship between physical theory and mathematics.
I apologize before asking if the questions are not appropriate. And I will be grateful to anyone who responds.

1. Special relativity (SR) was originally proposed by Albert Einstein in a paper published in **1905**. But Minkowski spacetime as a Mathematical structure for formulating SR introduced in **1908** (three years later)! I am confused about this. Did not Einstein himself state the mathematical framework of his theory? What is the difference between SR as Einstein himself formulated and SR in Minkowski's point of view?
   In fact, I always thought that every physical theory is formed at the same time as its mathematical formulation. Can we have a physical theory without any mathematical formulation?
2. I read in some textbooks or internet pages (I do not remember which book or page) that in Quantum theories in physics there are some calculations that led to correct answers but we have no mathematical explanation for why. How is such a thing possible? Aren't our calculations based on mathematics?

Comment: 1. I can't speak to the history of SR specifically, but generally the abstract generalization of a given mathematical concept comes after the first concrete usage of it (though that first usage may or may not be in physics). This might be surprising for something like SR but if you think back to more basic things like the real numbers themselves, the way this trend forms should be understandable.

Comment: 2. The main case of this that I know of is regularization of formally divergent calculations in quantum field theory, when the particular regularization that is used can't be mathematically proven to be "correct". Doing a calculation before you know how to rigorously prove that every step is pretty common. For example in numerical simulation, if you don't know the stability properties of the underlying system, you can't really be sure that your numerics aren't artificially dissipating away the instability that was always there.

Comment: Physical science is principally an empirical discipline and generally uses inductive reasoning from observing patterns in phenomena.  It has often _guided_ mathematical development, but physical models have generally preceded mathematical formulation.  The development of mathematical models (which have had to be "rejected" more often than they have been useful) in physical inquiry _in advance_ of observation is largely something that took hold in physics after the 1920's (much to the annoyance of the generation of physicists that worked during the '20s to '50's).  [continued]

Comment: Incidentally, while Einstein was a _terrific_ intuitionist, he actually had little interest in pure mathematics as a student.  (Funny you should mention Minkowski -- look up what he had to say about Einstein as a student...)  Marcel Grossman was instrumental in guiding Einstein toward the necessary mathematics for advancing his work, particularly after 1905.  E. was also in a bit of a panic when he learned that Hilbert had taken an interest in relativity theory and was working on a formulation of general relativity.

Comment: Along the same lines : Einstein said to [Georges Lemaitre](https://wordsforeveries.wordpress.com/2016/10/02/the-long-read-musings-about-the-universe-from-einsteins-general-relativity-to-current-observations-of-uniformity-expansion-and-dark-energy/) who was very talented and by some more positive thinkers called the "father of the big bang" : "Your mathematics is correct but your physics is abominable”.

Comment: @boojum Thank you all. Do you know a source or book that explains your points in more detail? I want to know how a physical theory can be formed without having and using precise mathematics? Especially in the case of Einstein's special relativity. If you can introduce a book in this field, especially mathematics in the opinion of Einstein and Minkowski and related to SR or GR, which is related to this question, I would be very grateful.

Comment: I believe, very strongly!, that you should move this question to the appropriate forum, https://hsm.stackexchange.com. You are only going to get chitchat here.

Comment: Maybe useful David Topper, [How Einstein Created Relativity out of Physics and Astronomy (Springer, 2013)](https://www.google.it/books/edition/How_Einstein_Created_Relativity_out_of_P/nd8O6GF7yCoC)

Comment: And Carl Helrich, [The Quantum Theory: Origins and Ideas A Historical Primer for Physics Students (Springer, 2021)](https://www.google.it/books/edition/The_Quantum_Theory_Origins_and_Ideas/PVk7EAAAQBAJ)

Comment: It is difficult to boil down so much history into only one book.  But certainly the history of celestial mechanics, classical mechanics, and electromagnetism shows that attempts to characterize phenomena long precede the development of a broadly-encompassing mathematical "formulation".  Some books related to what's been discussed here:  Goodstein, _Einstein's Italian Mathematicians_ ; Jones, _The Quantum Ten_ ; Woit, _Not Even Wrong_ ; there are plenty of others.  HSM.SE may have more to say, but varies a lot as to how extensive a discussion of a topic one may receive...